# How to Reference an interface to interact with classes that implement it?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I need to create an Employee that creates a CompensationModel property from the Interface. This property should choose a specific Model(class) that implements that interface. I should also be able to use methods from that model. However, I am only able to do this by referencing the classes themselves.
This shows what I am attempting to do in the constructor and how I have gotten it to work with the hourly class.

```
public class Employee {
private final String firstName;
private final String lastName;
private final String socialSecurityNumber;
private String model;
private double earnings = 0;
CompensationModel compensationModel;

// constructor
public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, 
  String socialSecurityNumber, String model) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
  this.model = model;
  if(model == "Salary"){
      compensationModel = new SalariedCompensationModel();
  }
} 
public void setHourly(double wage, double hours){
    HourlyCompensationModel s = new HourlyCompensationModel(wage, hours);
    s.setWage(wage);
    s.setHours(hours);
    this.earnings = s.earnings();
    
}
```

This is the interface that I am using.

```
public interface CompensationModel{
public abstract double earnings();
}
```

And this is the class it should be referencing.

```
public class SalariedCompensationModel implements CompensationModel{

private double weeklySalary;

public double getWeeklySalary(){return weeklySalary;}

public void setWeeklySalary(double weeklySalary){this.weeklySalary = weeklySalary;}

// calculate earnings; override abstract method earnings
@Override                                                           
public double earnings() {return getWeeklySalary();}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If a method is defined in a class, then you need an instance of that class to call it; that's what methods are for.

Comment: I am told I need to be able to create a CompensationModel property that would create the correct Model, like the SalariedModel, and assign it to the employee class. The CompensationModel should have common methods that are all implemented in the child classes so they can be called the same way from the Employee class when needed.

Comment: You most likely want `abstract class CompensationModel` instead of `interface` if you need to provide some implementation methods and some abstract methods.   Like what's the difference between `earnings` and `weeklySalary`? how do they relate